# SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol with requests on python

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm doing a small project at the university - extracting courses from university site and building ideal schedule.

while trying to access the website with requests i keep getting the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)
```

this problem only occurs while trying to reach the site i need. on any other sites there is no problem.

iv'e tried this previous solutions, with no luck:

- creating my own HTTPadapter with ssl version = TLSv1
- overriding ssl version in the ssl.py (context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_SSLv23))
- installing (which gave me another error) / removing pyOpenSSL

currently i'm trying to figure out what to do. i can "throw" this method away and try to extract the data with selenium but this will be very slow operation.

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is simply a problem with your python or SSL library installation locally. Please post your example code including the http endpoint to test against.  If you post something easy to reproduce, we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing is version specific I think it's 3.5 try installing some other version.Or try this it's not a solution for your problem but rather a work around.
Instead of using pyssl or any kind of ssl .
Make the request using like this.

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener  = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17')]
sou = opener.open(url).read()
```

Here url is intended target. Sou will hold the source code of the page.Then use either Beautifulsoup or re to get the intended data.
Hope it helps